# With what GUI framework is the Mono .NET Windows.Forms implemented?

Tags: .net, winforms, mono

With what GUI framework is the Mono .NET Windows.Forms implemented?

Example: KDE, Gnome, X11 itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mono does not use Qt (KDE) or GTK+ (GNOME) widgets because [they don't match up with the Winforms API](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms#Why_Not_Use_Native_Widgets.3F). Mono implements Winforms on top of their `System.Drawing` implementation, which in turn uses Cairo. Cairo deals with the native graphics implementation, such as X11 in Linux or Quartz in OS X.

Comment: To clarify: System.Windows.Forms is going through Cairo. Bindings for GTK (GtkSharp) and Qt (Qyoto) are also available, the first one being much more mature.